# Compare two voices and outline their similarity

Tags: fft, cross-correlation, mfcc, java

I am trying to develop an application which records the voice of someone through a microphone. I will have a preset recorded voices for the same words. I then need to compare the real time recorded voice with the list of recorded voices and output a similarity in percentage format.

I did a lot of literature research about this and I found that it can be done using several algorithms such as:

- FFT
- MFCC
- Cross-Correlation

My question is can this be done using JavaScript, PHP, MySQL ?

Or do I need to program this using Java or any other language? I really need some guidance in what to start looking for in order to start developing something and make it work.

I do not want to use any system that provides Text-To-Speech or vice versa. I purely want to analyse and compare audio files. This system will be used to aid people with speech disability so they wouldn't exactly know how to pronounce the exact words

Comment: You may be interested in this question: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/736/how-do-i-implement-cross-correlation-to-prove-two-audio-files-are-similar But realize that these are not fully ideal solutions because this doesn't account for differences in the speed at which the two speakers are speaking. The website/app "Duolingo" has a working version of the functionality which you are desire to implement although they may be less than willing to disclose it.

Comment: Also this question appears to be nearly exactly yours - http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/7581/speech-comparison-algorithm-for-rating-on-similarities

Comment: Do you have any strict time requirement for the analysis ? Or is it just like "I would like to present the results as soon as possible to the user" ? The languages you cited will allow you to perform almost any processing (at least for PHP), but they're not *made* for that kind of application, so they'll be quite slow to do so.